# Problems showing a web 3Dmodel viewer in the webBrowser control XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I am trying to show a url from Sketchfab and I can´t get the desired results. I need to show a page like this.

https://sketchfab.com/models/dGUrytaktlDeNudCEGKk31oTJY/embed?autospin=0.3&autostart=1&ui_infos=0

If you go there you can see that the model starts to spin automatically but if I put this Url in the source property of my WebBrowser control it shows the model but I doesn´t spin. The code that I am using is this:

```
<phone:PanoramaItem Header="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}, Path=LocalizedResources.MainPagePanoramaItemViewTitle}" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Grid>
                <phone:WebBrowser x:Name="WebBrowserViewer"  Background="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Height="450"
                Source="https://sketchfab.com/models/dGUrytaktlDeNudCEGKk31oTJY/embed?autospin=0.3&amp;autostart=1&amp;ui_infos=0"
                IsScriptEnabled="True"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </Grid>
        </phone:PanoramaItem>
```

Is posible reproduce this "autospin" and adjust de viewer to the WebBrowser control ?

Thanks a lot